# Is using a getter in a for-each loop inefficient?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop, optimization, foreach

Recently I have been doing the following in my code:

```
for(auto& item : something.getSomeVector())
```

As I started my optimization pass, I started to wonder if that is less efficient than something like the following:

```
std::vector<Type> vTypes = something.getSomeVector();
for(auto& item : vTypes)
```

Would a `for-each` loop copy the vector or just keep calling that function?

Thanks!

Comment: I see no reason why the compiler can't optimize that out, but the easiest way to find out is to write the benchmark, unless you prefer to read the assembly instead.

Comment: make a test or read assembly...

Comment: Sorry, what's the assembly? Google only shows up with conversions to assembly language.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The definition of range-based loop is that your code expands to something very similar to this, inside a block:

```
auto && __range = something.getSomeVector();
auto __begin = begin(__range);
auto __end = end(__range);

for (; __begin != __end; ++__begin)
{
    auto &item = *__begin;
```

So as you can see, it is already optimal and your suggested improvement may even make things worse (if the function returned by reference then you made a copy where none was made previously).

Comment: Minor remark not really relevant for this question: It is actually defined as `auto __begin = begin(__range), __end = end(__range);` which means that the two iterators are forced into the same type.

Comment: @5gon12eder thanks for pointing that out. I thought I was clarifying it but overlooked that nuance (although in theory `end` and `begin` should never get different types)

Comment: Yes, they shouldn't.  I was bitten by this recently when I thought I could get clever and have `begin()` and `end()` return different types…